# Transformation (rotation) of image using matrix - design-time vs. run-time rendering results

Tags: c#, graphics, matrix, rotation, transformation

I have a 48x48 image which is rotated using a transformation matrix.

For some reason, the rotated image in design-time differs from the rotated image in run-time as you can see from [<s>this screenshot (link dead)</s>](http://img210.yfrog.com/img210/8058/render.jpg) (design-time on the left, run-time on the right):

It might be a little bit difficult to spot, but if you look closely at the right edge of the blue circle, it is about a pixel wider in the image to the right. Note that the image is layered - the white glow in the foreground is the part that's being rotated, while the blue ball in the background is static.

It seems like the image is offset 1 pixel in run-time, when rotating exactly 90 degrees (as in the screenshot), 180 degrees and probably also 270 degrees. The image looks the same with any other rotation angle, as far as I can see.

Here's a snippet:

```
protected static Image RotateImage(Image pImage, Single pAngle)
    {
      Matrix lMatrix = new Matrix();
      lMatrix.RotateAt(pAngle, new PointF(pImage.Width / 2, pImage.Height / 2));
      Bitmap lNewBitmap = new Bitmap(pImage.Width, pImage.Height);
      lNewBitmap.SetResolution(pImage.HorizontalResolution, pImage.VerticalResolution);
      Graphics lGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(lNewBitmap);
      lGraphics.Transform = lMatrix;
      lGraphics.DrawImage(pImage, 0, 0);
      lGraphics.Dispose();
      lMatrix.Dispose();
      return lNewBitmap;
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
      // Same results in design-time and run-time:
      PictureBox1.Image = RotateImage(PictureBox2.Image, 18)
      // Different results in design-time and run-time.
      PictureBox1.Image = RotateImage(PictureBox2.Image, 90)
    }
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this behaviour? Or better yet, a solution to make run-time results look like design-time results?

It's important for me because this image is part of an animation which is generated from code based on a single image which is then rotated in small steps. In design-time, the animation looks smooth and nice. In run-time it looks like it's jumping around :/

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 on Windows Vista Business SP2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have something to do with differences in the Graphics object used at design time versus run time like the PixelOffsetMode.

Comment: Amazing! Changning Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to HighQuality caused the result to be even more satisfying than the current design-time results. The animation now looks perfect. Thanks a lot BlueMonkMN, you made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you specifying your angle of rotation? in Degrees or in Radians?

Sometimes I get results like those you describe when I've accidentally specified my angle in degrees when it should've been radians (and as a result the object has been rotated several hundred degrees instead of a few)

I don't know for sure given your specific example, but its worth suggesting.

Comment: Hi Phill, thank you for your response! Unfornutately this is not the source of the problem. The Matrix.RotateAt() method takes an angle argument that should be specified in degrees, which is what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, my consideration is to try:

```
lMatrix.RotateAt(pAngle, new PointF((pImage.Width + 1)/2.0f, (pImage.Height + 1)/ 2.0f));
```

Comment: I tested your suggestion, but it simply offsets the entire animation. The irregularities at 90, 180 and 270 degrees rotation still occur in run-time. I'd like to think that the code works just fine as it is, since the animation already looks perfect in design-time. What I'm wondering is what's causing the difference in run-time results.

Comment: That means I was wrong... So does the run-time angle values in 90, 180 and 270 placements are absolutely equal to that values?

Comment: The screenshot was taken at exactly 90 degrees rotation. At exactly 180 and 270 degrees rotation the image also seems to be slightly offset.

Comment: Really strange. Is your step fixed? If no, may be you can change it a bit and see how it will affect run-time?..

Comment: Yes, if I use a step size that avoids the 90/180/270 angles, there is no problem. I have posted a workaround below, which ensures that these angles are avoided altogether. I'm still wondering why this is necessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be a problem about the math being performed in floating point; when rounding back to integer coordinates.

One question that might be relevant... is your image completely square and the width and height an even number? Maybe the problem lies there.

**Edit**: In the first read I passed through the dimensions of the image... If that wasn't the problem maybe you could do a simple rotation by yourself:

```
angle = 90 : img[i][j] = img[j][w-i]
angle = 180: img[i][j] = img[w-i][w-j]
angle = 270: img[i][j] = img[w-j][i]
```

(I think the index swappings are ok, but a double check won't be bad)

Comment: I believe the transformation actually supports rotation around a floating point e.g. (24.5, 24.5), when using matrices. The Matrix.RotateAt method only accepts a PointF struct anyway.

I'm not sure how to use your example, but I solved the problem by setting the PixelOffsetMode property of the Graphics object to a higher value. This was the cause of the problem. If I wanted to use other means of rotating an image 90, 180 or 270 degrees, there is also the RotateFlip method on the Image class.

In any case, thanks for your input!